# Linq to XML if/foreach with XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-xml

It seems I am having a bit of trouble with Linq to XML, I have looked for tutorials, but nothing really tells me about from, select, statements.  I would like to know how to do a foreach/if statements with linq, if you have a tutorial please let me know.  My problem right now is I only want a certain part put into my XML if the textbox has something in it.

The code obviously does not work as you cannot put if statements withing my XDocument. Any help/explanation would be very great

```
if(txtPr3_Chain.Text != "")
                            {
                        new XElement("Property_Info",
                          new XAttribute("Chain", txtPr3_Chain.Text),  
                        new XElement("City" ,txtPr3_City.Text ),
                        new XElement("AdRating" ,AdRating3.CurrentRating.ToString()),
                        new XElement("YourRating" ,YourRating3.CurrentRating.ToString() ),
                        new XElement("Comment" ,txtPr3_Comments.Text)),
                            }
```

Comment: The code you have posted is pretty meaningless and you don't really explain what you want to do or what you mean by a foreach/if statement.  You can certainly iterate through a collection using foreach and then do something conditional within the loop using an if statement.  This does not have much to do with LINQ though.

Comment: I will try to be clearer next time, though everyone else seemed to understand, as each answer helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create the XDocument with the parts that are always there and then insert/append the other parts after, where you can use a regular for or if

Comment: thanks, this worked with the combo of the first answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you simply attempting to construct a new `XElement` when the Text value is not empty?

Try this:

```
XElement element = null;
if (txtPr3_Chain.Text != "")
{
    element = new XElement("Property_Info",
                            new XAttribute("Chain", txtPr3_Chain.Text),
                            new XElement("City", txtPr3_City.Text),
                            new XElement("AdRating", AdRating3.CurrentRating.ToString()),
                            new XElement("YourRating", YourRating3.CurrentRating.ToString()),
                            new XElement("Comment", txtPr3_Comments.Text));
}
```

Comment: thanks this works, though for the future, I will be doing more foreach type loops, within the Xdocument... if you have any tutorials that would be great, as I can't seem to find any good ones

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not a bad idea to always include all those nodes, even when they're empty
2. If you insist, you can write an enumerator-method that yields non-empty fields:

```
 //untested
IEnumerable<Xelement> GetFields()
{
    if (txtPr3_City.Text != null)
      yield return new Xelement("City",txtPr3_City.Text);
    ....    
}


 element = new XElement("Property_Info",
               new XAttribute("Chain", txtPr3_Chain.Text),
               GetFields());
```